# jQuery (1.7.2 - latest) - weird behaviour when setting CSS values (decimals/float errors)

Tags: jquery, css, floating-point, rounding

I've been testing a simple loop which moves something across the screen - but I'm seeing odd behaviour (almost certainly related to float errors) when setting CSS Properties through jQuery.

Basically I do something like this repeatedly

```
var val = parseInt($(myobject).css("left));
val -= 7;
$(myobject).css("left",val+"px");
```

If I test the value of the "left" property after that, I'll see results such as

```
1042
1035
1028
1020 <<<< !!!!
1013
1006
...
```

Digging further, what seems to be happening is that I do this

```
$(myobject).css("left","1021px")
alert($(myobject).css("left"))
```

and what the alert shows is "1020.99876152371253716253px"

All I can think is that jQuery is internally stripping the "1021px" and assigning a non-rounded/fixed/ceiled/floored version of the number!?

Not sure where to raise this as a problem or if I'm missing something!?!?

p.s. updating to say I'm seeing this on latest public Chrome/W7-64

p.p.s. I copied my entire code (sans a webfont and 1 external function) into JSFiddle and it doesn't misbehave (even in fullscreen) - but the code continues to misbehave when run standalone (despite being identical code in every respect!!) so I'm ever more mystified by this...

and more p.s. this only happens in Chrome, in IE (9) and Firefox (14) it works AOK - so clearly I have chanced on a quirk, and a very specific one at that (as it's not reproducible in jsFiddle!!)

Comment: I don't get that result when I test it in Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome - latest non-development version on Windows7-64 - I'll add that to the post

Comment: I tested it in Chrome 20.0.1132.57, and I don't get that result there either.

Comment: My Chrome says 20.0.1132.57 m - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2. Here's the test: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/k4e35/

Comment: I think you've oversimplified that to the point of being pointless - did you read what I'm actually doing!? :)

Comment: What do you mean? I tested the code in your question. Did you simplify the example so much that it doesn't exibit the problem any more?

Comment: It's not an example - I'm demonstrating what my code (which is moving dozens of objects onscreen) is producing when it's debugged.

My program isn't just 2 lines of code - although, in effect, my program assigns "1021px" to the "left" property and when you query that property again, jQuery returns "1020.99234762347px" or something like that

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem with those lines, then that's not what's happening. Most likely you have a loss of precision that is growing with each iteration, and is made worse by the conversion between a numeric value and string. When you think that you are assigning `1021px` you are actually assigning `1020.99234762347px` that was produced from a numeric value like `1020.9923476234748`, and as each conversion to a string loses some digits at the end, you don't get the same value back when you later parse it to a numeric value. Keeping the value numeric all the way would solve that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14701/discussion-between-john-peat-and-guffa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is assigning the value that you specified ("1021px"). It's the browser that is producing the float value. I had a similar issue in one version of IE a while ago.

You can deal with this like so:

```
var val = Math.round( parseFloat( $( myobject ).css( 'left' ) ) );
```

Comment: I actually tried something like that but I used Math.ceil - which just led me into errors in the opposite direction after a while!

I'll try it with Round() instead and report back!

Comment: Yup - that works...

My other solution was to add ".1" into the assignment string, so I'm actually setting the "left" properly to "1021.1px" which seems to eliminate this 'rounding under' - but Math.Round is a better solution I think

Comment: Given how obscure this is to reproduce, this seems as good an answer as any (it fits any situation where a browser chooses to report fractional positions!)

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't parse the value at all, use a variable to keep the value and only set the style.

Example:

```
$(document).load(function(){
  var x = 2000;
  var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if (x > 10) {
      x -= 7;
      $('.myobject').css("left", x + "px");
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: There are several moving objects - which can be dragged around by the user too! - so I'm pretty-much stuck with the "read it - change it - post it back" approach.  Thanks tho!

Comment: @JohnPeat: As long as it's your code that is moving the objects around, you can always keep track of the positions in the code and not only in the style. Using the data methods in jQuery is one way of associating data with different elements. Local variables in a closure is another way of keeping several instances of data associated with event handlers for each element.